# Json to CSV to download working in chrome but not working in IE browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer-8, export-to-csv

Json to CSV to download working in chrome but not working in IE browser ? Any body have solution for 
this.

Json Data :

```
[
  {
    "id":1,    "name":"Johnson, Smith, and Jones Co.",
    "amount":345.33,    "Remark":"Pays on time"
  },
  {
    "id":2,    "name":"Sam \"Mad Dog\" Smith",
    "amount":993.44,    "Remark":""
  },
  {
    "id":3,    "name":"Barney & Company",
    "amount":0,    "Remark":"Great to work with\nand always pays with cash."
  },
  {
    "id":4,    "name":"Johnson's Automotive",
    "amount":2344,    "Remark":""
  }
]
```

Function :

```
JSONToCSVConvertor = function (JSONData, Filename, ColumnDataTypes, ShowLabel) 
{
       var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;
       var array = ColumnDataTypes.split(',');
       var CSV = '';
       var ColumnName = ColumnDataTypes.split(',');
       if (ShowLabel) {
           var row = "";
           for (var x = 0; x < array.length ; x++) {
               row += array[x].split('-')[1] + ',';
           }
       }
       row = row.slice(0, -1);
       //append Label row with line break
       CSV += row + '\r\n';
       for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
          var row = "";

          for (Col = 0; Col < array.length; Col++) {
              row += ('"' + arrData[i][array[Col].split('-')[0]] + '",').replace('""', '"');
          }
           row.slice(0, row.length - 1);
           //add a line break after each row
           CSV += row + '\r\n';
       }

       if (CSV == '') {
           alert("Invalid data");
           return;
       }

       //Generate a file name
       var fileName = Filename;

       //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
       var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
       var link = document.createElement("a");
       link.href = uri;
       //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
       link.style = "visibility:hidden";
       link.download = fileName + ".csv";
       //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
       document.body.appendChild(link);
       link.click();
       document.body.removeChild(link);
};
```

Comment: what happens in IE? Any errors thrown?

Comment: can you please update this code JSFIDDLe (it should work for chrome) or is it possible to provide the live website, where we can check.

Comment: Exception is "the data area passed to a system call is too small".

Answer (score 0):

I found this post while trying to solve the same problem.

My solution was to use the "[Papa Parse](http://papaparse.com/docs#json-to-csv)" library to create the CSV file and use [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to actually make local data appear as a file which can be downloaded.

I also tried directly setting base64 encoded data to the window [like this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396580/ajax-and-downloading-csv-file#33396814) but it choked on my 6-10MB report results.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //My json formatted data from php.
  var dataSet = <?=json_encode($data)?>;
  //select our link, create an objectURL Blob of CSV data.
  jQuery('#downloadCsv').attr('href',URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([Papa.unparse(dataSet)], { type:"text/csv" } ) ) );
});
```

and the html for the link:

```
<a id="downloadCsv" class="button button-secondary" download="reportdata.csv">Download CSV</a>
```