# Ajax and downloading CSV file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

I'm trying to build a "Export to CSV" system using ajax so 
this is my ajax call

```
$(document).on('click', '#export-csv', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: export_url,
        type: 'post',
        data:{ validations: validations },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 1000000,
        success: function (data) {
            var resp = data.response;
            console.log(resp);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

and this is my php code to convert an array to csv

```
public function exportCsvAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {

        $input = $request->getPost();
        $response = $this->getResponse();

        $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        foreach ($input['validations'] as $line) {
            fputcsv($file, $line, chr(9), '"');
        }
        fclose($file);

        header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="validations-' . time() . '.csv"');

        return $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode(array('response' => true)));
    }
    return $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(400);
}
```

Everything is working. My ajax returns success but now I'm stuck...

How to download the file after a successfully ajax call? What is the next step?

I already did my research and I found nothing relevant and/or helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Return the url of the .csv file in your ajax call. Then in your success function put:

```
location.href = url;
```

Just like all file types that are not naturally handled by the browser this will cause the browser to download the file.

Comment: This reloads the whole file again, making the AJAX load redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating `a` element with `href` attribute set to `data URI` of file using `URL.createObjectURL` , `Blob` ; `download` attribute to set file name for "Save file" dialog

```
success: function (data) {
            var resp = data.response;
            var a = $("<a />", {
               href: "data:text/csv," 
                     + URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([resp], {
                         type:"text/csv"
                       })),
               "download":"filename.csv"
            });
            $("body").append(a);
            a[0].click();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, perfectly.

```
 jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.btn_generate_product', function(e) {

var product_id = jQuery(this).data('product_id');

jQuery.ajax({
    url : "ajaxurl", 
    type: 'POST',
    data: { product_id },
    success: function(data){

          /*
           * Make CSV downloadable
           */
          var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
          var fileData = ['\ufeff'+data];

          var blobObject = new Blob(fileData,{
             type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;"
           });

          var url = URL.createObjectURL(blobObject);
          downloadLink.href = url;
          downloadLink.download = "products.csv";

          /*
           * Actually download CSV
           */
          document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
          downloadLink.click();
          document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);

    }
});
});
```