# WordPress - Export table as csv using jQuery/Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, csv

**Question:**: I am developing a plugin. This plugins creates a custom table in WP database. How can I export the data from this table using Ajax?

**Where I am?**: I have created the hook and the handler. I can actually grab the data. Please see my code below.

```
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_exportcsv', 'exprot_to_csv' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_exportcsv', 'exprot_to_csv' );    

<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery("#export-csv").on("click",function(e){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {"action":"exportcsv"},
            success: function(response){alert(response);}
            })
        });</script>        


function exprot_to_csv(){

global $wpdb;
$table_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
$table = $table_prefix.'my_custom_table';

$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$table."");
    foreach ($result as $row) {

        $output .="\n";
        $output .='"'.$row->post_id.'",';
        }
        $output .="\n";
        $file = "custom_table";
        $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
        header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");

        echo $output;
        exit;

}
```

In the alert box, I am getting comma separated post IDs as expected. But I am not sure how to move on from here. I mean how to handle this response and prompt the user to save/download the file.

Any help?

Comment: Can you check with your FTP to see if in the root of the wp folder you have a `.csv` file?

Comment: Just checked. Its not in the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download CSV file using "AJAX"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346072/download-csv-file-using-ajax)

Comment: @dingo_d, I did have checked that. But he is getting a file created in the server but can't show the download dialogue box. While my file isn't actually being created.

Comment: How not? Just put the contents of your function `exprot_to_csv()` to `exprot_to_csv.php`, and call that file on click ;) Should be working :)

Comment: Hahaha. I got what you meant :-) So there is no apparent way that I can get this directly via a function rather than a file?

Comment: Well I haven't try. I know that I always got the `headers already sent...` error when I tried something similar to that. You can see the output in the Networks tab in the inspector when you trigger the ajax call, see if there is errors beside the returned ID's.

Comment: Apparently I am lucky here. I do not see any errors :-)

Comment: @dingo_d, so I inserted the code into a separate export.php and when I call that file on click using window.location.href, wordpress gives me error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: You can't return a file via ajax. Make a post request to your method returning header("Content-Type: text/csv"); or header("Content-Disposition: attachment") if you'd like to save the file first

Comment: Maybe this answer can point you a way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33396810/5970334

Comment: You have to use action: **exprot_to_csv** , not **exportcsv**. But seem ajax can't download a file. I also have same problem. Anyone help me an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You are close...! I ran into same problem, tried a similar solution.

**Check this question out:**
[Download file through an ajax call php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668776/download-file-through-an-ajax-call-php)

**And THIS specific answer:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11452917
Make sure to look at Dario's answer

**Summary** -

1. AJAX is not for streaming downloads.
2. The solution here is to *make an iFrame*
3. Load a *PHP file into that iFrame* using jQuery
4. Serve up your file with a *File Transfer*

   ```
   'header('Content-Description: File Transfer');'
   ```

This works in WordPress. Use Admin-Ajax.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

In jQuery:

```
 window.location = response->in success
```

Action ajax:

**Please remove all headers**

```
echo admin_url($filename);
die;
```